# CGAffineTransformRotate does not go back to original state after repeated clicks

Tags: ios, animation

On one click, ImageView is rotated then goes back to original state. However on repeated fast clicks, the image view does not go back to original state. Any ideas why not? Here's the code:

```
int repeatCounter = 20;

NSLog(@"Rotate animate started");
[imageView.layer removeAllAnimations];

// Set image
if ([imageView isEqual:rideImageView]){
    [rideImageView setImage:rideImage];
}
else{
    [crashImageView setImage:crashImage];
}

CGAffineTransform rotateStart = CGAffineTransformRotate(imageView.transform, 0.2);
CGAffineTransform rotateEnd = CGAffineTransformRotate(imageView.transform, 0.0f);


// this spin completes 360 degrees every 2 seconds
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration/repeatCounter
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
                     [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:repeatCounter];
                     imageView.transform = rotateStart;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                           NSLog(@"Rotate animate completed");

                     imageView.transform = rotateEnd;

                     if (finished) {

                         NSLog(@"Rotate animate finished but after repeated clicks is permanently rotated");

                         if ([imageView isEqual:rideImageView]){
                             [rideImageView setImage:rideLabelledImage];
                         }
                         else{
                             [crashImageView setImage:crashLabelledImage];
                         }
                     }
                    }
                 ];
```

Comment: I think you need a flag, and when the animation is on don't start another

Comment: Nice idea, Reinier, but where do you get the handle to check if animating?

Comment: You can add an if check before the animate block after that set the animating variable to true and in the finish callback set the animating variable to false, I can provide an answer if you like

Comment: Actually, it turns out that but it does not have the desired result. The animation needs to start again on every click. We don't wish to prevent the animation from starting.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45592182/core-animation-modify-animation-property/45595503#45595503 @TomV maybe can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0); as a rotation end. Here's the code:

```
 [imageView.layer removeAllAnimations];

// Set image
[crashImageView setImage:crashImage];

CGAffineTransform rotateStart = CGAffineTransformRotate(imageView.transform, 0.2);
CGAffineTransform rotateEnd  = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);

int repeatCounter = 20;

// Rattles to and fro
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration/repeatCounter
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
                     [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:repeatCounter];
                     imageView.transform = rotateStart;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     //NSLog(@"Rotate animate completed");

                     // Ensure back to original state whether or not animation has completely finished
                     imageView.transform = rotateEnd;

                     if (finished) {

                         //NSLog(@"Rotate animate finished but after repeated clicks is permanently rotated");
                         [crashImageView setImage:crashLabelledImage];
                     }
                 }
 ];
```