# How can I calculate the duration of an ease-out animation to achieve a desired initial velocity?

Tags: ios, animation, calayer, caanimation

**Context:**

I have a graphic that I rotate continuously while a background operation happens:

```
CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotationAnimation.toValue = @(M_PI * 2.0);
rotationAnimation.duration = 2;
rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;

[myImgView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
```

At some point this background animation ends, and I stop the animation:

```
[myImgView.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

When I do this, though, the rotation stops wherever it is and snaps back to zero rotation. I could just stop it where it is by promoting the presentation value to the model value:

```
CATransform3D stoppedTransform = myImgView.layer.presentationLayer.transform;
[myImgView.layer removeAllAnimations];
myImgView.layer.transform = stoppedTransform;
```

This works OK. But ideally I'd like to continue the rotation for the rest of its current circuit, and decelerate and stop smoothly as it approaches and rests at zero rotation. Stop the animation, promote presentation to model, and create a new animation with an ease-out curve to zero. Something like this:

```
CATransform3D stoppedTransform = myImgView.layer.presentationLayer.transform;
[myImgView.layer removeAllAnimations];
myImgView.layer.transform = stoppedTransform;
CGFloat currRotation = [[myImgView.layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];
CABasicAnimation *finishAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
finishAnimation.fromValue = @(currRotation);
finishAnimation.toValue = @(0);
finishAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
finishAnimation.duration = 2; //this is what I need to calculate correctly
[myImgView.layer setValue:@(0) forKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
[myImgView.layer addAnimation:finishAnimation forKey:@"transform.rotation.z"];
```

**My question:**

How do I calculate the duration of my finishing animation with its ease-out curve so that its initial velocity matches the velocity of the existing rotation (currently pi radians per second) so there's no visible hiccup? Or is there another way to achieve the desired effect?

I have tried using `CASpringAnimation` and using its `initialVelocity` property, but it seems to combine that with the velocity imparted by the spring pulling on the mass, which is governed by `mass`, `stiffness`, and `damping`, and its units are unclear. And I can get close on the ease-out duration by calculating the duration as if it's linear and bumping it 20% or 30% or so.

---

Side note: there is some minor complexity here, removed to simplify the question, around the `toValue` of `finishAnimation` because of how the layer reports its current rotation value. If it's more than pi radians (180 degrees), it reports as negative. So it goes like this:

```
CGFloat rotationRadians = currRotation / M_PI;
if (rotationRadians < 0)
{
    finishAnimation.duration = (-1 * rotationRadians); //negative means more than halfway through, or more than pi radians.
    finishAnimation.toValue = @(0);
}
else
{
    finishAnimation.duration = (2 - rotationRadians); //positive means less than halfway through, or less than pi radians
    finishAnimation.toValue = @(M_PI * 2);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is useful as I am unfamiliar with caannimation, but generically speaking.

currentRotation/2PI gives you rotation fractionCompleted.

timePerRotation - fractionCompleted * timePerRotation 
gives you time left for entire exit sequence. 

Hope that helps. Let me know if it does.

Comment: @MahdeTo sure, but that's for a linear animation. I want to know about ease-out.

Comment: See if this helps. I think it does what you want but no one every checked me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45592182/core-animation-modify-animation-property/45600277#45600277

Comment: @agibson007 close, but you're not setting an animation curve for your finish animation, which means it's probably defaulting to linear, which makes the duration calculation trivial. I want to ease to a stop.

Comment: Yep your right. But wouldn’t ease out set as the timing function start at the current velocity and ease out using what I did.

Comment: @agibson007 no, an ease-out curve for a given animation and duration will start faster than a linear curve for the same, because it has to move faster at the beginning to slow down later and still cover the same distance in the same time.

Comment: I got. Brain on something else. I see the issue. I was think of this huge number on the repeat count that there was not way it was slowing but it actually completes so it is slowing down. Yep I probably could figure it if I have time

Comment: You good with a custom easing curve for ease out. Otherwise I don’t know how to get apples control points.